# What happens when questions are migrated twice?

Tags: support, bug

[A question I answered](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116081/a-word-for-something-thats-done-only-half-consciously/116083#116083) was closed and presumably automagically migrated to Writers. I lost some rep because the question was no longer on ELU.

It's since been migrated back because it is actually relevant here and not there. But it appears that although rep is lost when a question is migrated away, it's not regained if the question reappears. In fact the system appears to have forgotten me: my account name isn't a link and the Gravatar is the default "deleted user" brown icon.

[image: Deactivated user card]

I **guess** this has happened because I don't have an account on Writers. Other accounts on that question are still linked following its repatriation.

While losing 103 rep is not going to affect me much, it might have a greater effect on less established members.

Should rep which is removed on migration be restored if the question is returned? Does it really depend on having an account on both sites?

Comment: I pinged one of the SE employees to see if they can take a look

Comment: That is annoying. But you can't expect the software to have imagined _all_ contingencies (keeping rep around inn case it gets migrated back). A meta question (like you just did) or a flag to a moderator is probably all that it takes to at least get considered.

Comment: @Mitch Yes; and as I say, I'm not especially worried. But I wonder what would have happened if I had had a Writers account.

Comment: Ha! And now I see that the question has been deleted entirely by a mod. That's one solution. Why was that done?

Comment: @AndrewLeach One of the people who works for SE cleared the migration history of the original question. You should be all set, now. (And double migrations apparently always break things, so having an account on Writers may not have helped much)

Comment: @simchona The question has been unilaterally deleted on ELU in the mistaken belief that [it exists on Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/search?q=writing+fiction+absentmindedly). It's been migrated from Writers and no longer exists anywhere.

Comment: @andrew check your first link. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116081/a-word-for-something-thats-done-only-half-consciously/116083#116083

Comment: That link links to 116237, which is deleted. I can get to 116081, but only by entering that number explicitly. And there's no record of the migrations in my rep chart either. Something is definitely broken here. It looks like the *earlier* version should have been deleted, not the later copy (which would need the unlinked accounts to be relinked).

Comment: For the second part of your comment, a SE employee did the undeletion. I don't think deleting the newer one did any harm; double migrations aren't supposed to happen and (as said by another mod) "always break something and shouldn't be allowed to happen". Also, your rep from the question does show up. Because its the older question, it shows up under the older dates (the 7th) as well as today because of new votes.

Comment: I'm also not sure why the link isn't working for you; it's working fine for me.

Comment: No idea. Perhaps the iPad's caching is more aggressive than it looks. It's working now. (If double migrations shouldn't happen, then the system should not automagically migrate in the first place. It only takes one erroneous vote to migrate to cause that to happen.)

Comment: I'm not sure why it's allowed; I'll ask Anna later. Glad the link works for you now. I also wonder if the Writers migration path should be removed, since there seems to be confusion about what's on topic there.